# Custom menu located in right bottom corner of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm doing some testing with a bootstrap responsive website, so I would like to have a logo left and right a Nav menu, but in the right bottom corner of the container.

When I simply add the navigation it goes by default right upper corner if I use float of-course. Now I can move the menu down by doing `margin-top:100px` for example, but then when I start to shrink the website making it smaller the divs will jump down and I will still have that margin top, but in this case I would prefer not to have it.

Any idea how to do it?

```
 <div class="container" style="min-height:170px">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px dashed;> 
            <a class="" href="#">
            <img alt="Brand" src="logo.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu" class="col-sm-8" style="border: 1px dashed; min-height:120px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">m1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">m2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">m3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you add screenshot?

Comment: You can remove the margin using media queries if you want. You can set specific CSS styles for each ID or Class for every width of the screen. In your case you could remove the margin at a width you think works best.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this class "col-md-offset-x" e.g "col-md-offset-6"on your brand-it will automatically set the appropriate margin for you and keeps it responsive.
but remember,if you don't want to disrupt the responsive ability of the website-try to avoid using 100px -instead ,you can use 100% for example .